# Putting my code to sleep using: time.sleep() will not use my PC resources? rams/CPU/etc?

Tags: time, cpu, sleep, ram

When I, for example, put my code to sleep like this: time.sleep(172800) [48 hours]

The code will still use my PC resources? rams/CPU/etc...?

Answer (score 1):

**CPU no**.  Your code itself won't run until it wakes up.  And OSes are pretty good at not slowing down scheduling decisions just from having more processes existing in a not-ready-to-run state.

Things like a load-monitor that totals up info about every process in the system will have one more process (and all its threads) to read about, e.g. an extra entry in Linux's `/proc/` virtual directory.  But these are secondary effects, and not really something to worry much about.

---

**RAM, yes any dirty pages in your process are state that has to be available when you wake up.**  The kernel may swap them out if there's available space in the page file, or compress them to fit 3 pages of RAM in one physical page (Linux `zswap`, and I think other OSes do this too).  In that case you're not using up as much physical RAM, stopping it from being used to cache files to speed up other processes, like it could if your process had instead exited and started fresh later.

Ideally try to free memory you don't need before sleeping for a long time.

Clean pages mapped by your process can just get evicted and read back from disk files (by a page fault) when needed later.  e.g. machine code in the `.text` section of an executable, if it didn't need runtime relocations for ASLR.  And read-only data.

Of course, most desktops are tuned to not be very aggressive with swapping things out, to avoid a slow response time when you do alt-tab back to a program for example.  IDK if any take into account that you're sleeping with a long-duration sleep system call instead of just waiting for an event that might not come soon.  In the sleep case, waking up soon is unlikely.  (Most sleeps can be interrupted by signals from other processes, so it's not impossible.)  On a server, Linux's default tuning of `vm.swappiness = 60` is more appropriate, and it will evict or swap pages out to disk just to free up that memory for caching actively-used file data.

A running process also has some associated kernel data structures and memory pages that the kernel can't or won't evict, like its kernel stack, and its page tables, and process-control-block.  (e.g. in Linux, its `task_struct`.)  This is pretty small on a machine with a few GiB of RAM, but don't start thousands or millions of threads if you don't need to.